# iPhone 3 v 4 v iPad ui. Raster vs vector

Tags: iphone

I'm the design guy on a new iPhone project and am curious on the eat practices for the up elements in the iPhone 3-4 dev. I know the dpi is different between the two and am curious how best to handle this with the dev guys. Do I need to make 2 of everything or do we need to figure how to make vectors of things like buttons , backgrounds and other images?

Any help , examples and links would be awesome. My goal is to do the best for the app with asking for dumb things from the developer

Thanks

Comment: I have been working on making a UIImage analogue that supports SVG vector images for illustrations and the like. Idea is to rasterize the image once you have the scale right and whatnot, and when you want to throw it in an image view, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option right now is to generate PDF images, then draw them manually with core graphics if you absolutely need vector graphics. Otherwise, you can wait for someone (including myself) to get something written third-party like, or you can just make two of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 files.

Lets say you have an image that is 48x48 called Hello.png

the hires version will be 96x96 called Hello@2x.png

The iPhone will automatically determine which image to use.

Thank you, come again.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. If you use `-[UIImage imageNamed:]` and aren't transforming it into a CGImage to apply something like a clipping mask or otherwise, then yes, you are right. The moment you start playing with custom drawing, even if you're grabbing the @2x image, you can loose the resolution and it looks like you loaded the standard sized image. The problem is worse if you want to download the image off a web service, since you then have to make sure you download the @2x image if you're on a device with a retina display. It's not as cut and dry as Apple would like you to think.

Comment: Do the files need to be 2x exactly the original?

Comment: Yes they do. Luckily, powers of 2 scale pretty damned well down in powers of 2. So developing the image in @2x scale, then scaling down to standard size will save you some time.